# Tomcat : Required request part 'file' is not present

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, multipartform-data, multipart

I am using Spring Boot to test a upload functionality, and getting 'Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present' error. 
when it deployed external tomcat server. 
but it properly works with spring boot tomcat plugin
Following are the 1) JSP, 2) Controller 3) Config property

1)

```
<form id="initialUploadForm" action="${root}/upload/uploadCapFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <table align="left" width="50%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"
                       border="0" class="formTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td><label class="">Add Cap File : </label></td>
                        <td><input type="file" name="file" style="width:100%;"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit"
                                   value="Upload Data" id="btnInitialUpload"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
</form>
```

2)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "uploadCapFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        ModelAndView uploadCapFileData(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model) {
            try {
                if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug("UploadController  calling : ");

                System.out.println("File Name : " + file.getOriginalFilename());
                long lStartTime = new Date().getTime();
                    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());
                        if (extension.equals(Constants.FILE_FORMAT)) {
                            File convFile = convertFile(file);
                            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(convFile);
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
                            String line;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                out.append(line);
                            }
                            if (isProdUpdate == 1) {
                                hotelService.updateAgentMarkup(out.toString());
                            } else {
                                hotelService.updateHotelData(out.toString());
                            }
                        } else {
                            log.error("Invalid File Format ! File Format is :" + Constants.FILE_FORMAT);
                        }
                    } else {
                        log.error("File is missing ! Can not be Process");
                    }


                long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();
                long output = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(lEndTime - lStartTime);
                processingTime = String.valueOf(output);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Error occurred while calling the UploadController : " + e);
            } catch (TalcacheException e) {
                log.error("Error occurred while calling the UploadController  : " + e.getErrorMsg());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error occurred while calling the UploadController : " + e);
            }
    }
```

3)

```
 spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
 spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=5KB
 spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
 spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code into config file

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
  CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
  multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(-1);
  return multipartResolver;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `multipart/form-data` in method signature.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "uploadCapFile", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers = "content-type=multipart/form-data")
```